# Is it possible to overload static method by closure signature in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, closures, overloading

Is it possible to overload static method by *closure type* in Swift 3?
For example, i have a struct with 2 methods:

```
struct Some {
  static func doSomething(first: String, @escaping completion: ([Int]?) -> Void) {
    ...
  }

  static func doSomething(first: String, @escaping completion: ([Int]?, String?) -> Void) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But when i try to call the first method `Some.doSomething(first: "Hello") { (numbers) in ... }` (with closure with **one** parameter) compiler gives me an error:

> Ambiguous use of 'doSomething(first:completion:)'

Comment: i have not tried it but suggest you try fully specify the competion parameters Some.doSomething(first: "Hello") { (numbers: [Int]?) -> Void in  ... }

Comment: @Bruce0 Yes, it worked. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes you can overload static method by closure type in Swift 3, but you
>   need to specify the type of the parameter for the first function as 
>   its parameters partially  matches with that of second function

```
 Some.doSomething(first: "") { (number:[Int]?) in

}

Some.doSomething(first: "") { (number, value) in

}
```